# Send HEX commands using Visual Basic 2005

Tags: vb.net, tcp, hex, lan

Good day to all,

i just registered on the forum because i really need help. the thing is that i just started using Visual Studio 2005 (because that's what we have here) and my intention is to communicate to a device using TCP LAN, i know the IP and port of the device.....the problem is that the device only recognises hex values for commands. the only thing that i've been able to do is do some kind of chat program between 2 pcs usin winsockets to enable the IP/port comunication but as you know chat programs only send strin arrays.

this is an example of what i need to do.

i have 2 textboxes on the form one named command1 and the other send_receive

on command1 textbox i manually input a HEX i need to send, for example... 05 6C 29 F1 3C 81
with that, the device needs to answer me with... 0C 00 6C F1 29 7C 81 30 34 31 34 39 39

and on the send_receive textbox i need to see with autoscroll the command i sent followed by the command i received...

somekind of visually it would look like this.. well sort of

--command1 textbox--

05 6C 29 F1 3C 81

--send_receive textbox--

<-- 05 6C 29 F1 3C 81
--> 0C 00 6C F1 29 7C 81 30 34 31 34 39 39

so were i' stuck at is changing from 05 6C 29 F1 3C 81 string in textbox to a hex 05 6C 29 F1 3C 81 for sending...

here is the code for what i have done, remember it has been done for chat purposes between 2 pcs, i need to know what i need to change in order to get the mentioned above, it's a short code so i'll post it all just in case it helps someone :D

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class Form1
    Dim listener As New TcpListener(1001)
    Dim client As TcpClient
    Dim message As String = ""

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    listener.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    listener.Start()
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Try
        If listener.Pending = True Then
            message = ""
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(client.GetStream())
            While reader.Peek > -1
                message = message + Convert.ToChar(reader.Read()).ToString
            End While
            Me.Focus()
            TextBox4.Text = (TextBox4.Text + message + vbCrLf)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Enter a username, enter a valid IP, enter a port, and enter a message.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

        Else
            client = New TcpClient(TextBox2.Text, 1001)
            Dim writer As New StreamWriter(client.GetStream())
            writer.Write(TextBox3.Text)
            writer.Flush()
            TextBox3.Text = ""
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Best regards and i hope you can help me.

Comment: "If you need the actual code I have just ask and I can upload it so you can see it." Yes, that would be helpful. Edit your post and add the code. Make sure you post only small amounts of code, only what's relevant to your problem. People here will likely not write it for you, but will help you with specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Convert.ToByte` method to convert a hex value to a byte. Split the string into separate hex codes and convert each one to a byte, then you can write them to the stream.

Note that you should use the client stream directly, as a `StreamWriter` only writes text to a stream, not bytes.

```
Dim parts As String() = TextBox3.Text.Split(" "C)
Dim bytes(parts.Length) As Byte
For i As Integer = 0 To parts.Length - 1
  bytes(i) = Convert.ToByte(parts(i), 16)
Next
client = New TcpClient(TextBox2.Text, 1001)
Dim stream As Stream = client.GetStream()
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
stream.Flush()
```

When you read the data you can convert the character code to hex representation:

```
message = message + reader.Read().ToString("x2") + " "
```

The streamreader migh try to decode the data to characters using a specific encoding, so if the response isn't really possible to handle as text you might need to read it from the client stream without using a stream reader in between.

Comment: Good day, trying to use your method, i get the following error on this part: "Dim bytes As Byte(parts.Length)".... the error is, array bound cannot appear in type specifier and theres a blue line below parts... do you know what it means?

Comment: @MiguelHunter: Sorry, I got the syntax backwards there. The size goes after the identifier. I updated the code above.

Comment: yea i was looking at that on another example in the web XD, but now i'm getting 4 errors corresponding to stream stream=client.getstream(), it's putting it as stream(stream=client.getstream())... adding parentesis after the first stream... and i suppose that the other 3 ar linked to this one..

Comment: @MiguelHunter: Ah, there's some C# syntax bleeding through, it should be a `Dim` statement. I updated the code.

Comment: @MiguelHunter: I think that you should use the same stream for reading and writing. See example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the list of hex commands to a byte array and sending that:

```
    Try
        Dim cmds As New List(Of Byte)
        For Each cmd As String In TextBox1.Text.Trim.Split(" ")
            cmds.Add(Convert.ToByte(cmd, 16))
        Next
        Dim bytes() As Byte = cmds.ToArray
        client.GetStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Hex Command")
    End Try
```

Comment: Really?...in the Else block of your original Button1 Click handler right underneath the line where you have `client = ...`.  This code could replace the 3 "writer" lines you have in there.

Comment: dude i'm sorry if i do not not get it the firt time, i've only worked with visual basic for no more that 8 hours... all this is new to me :(